# How can I conform 2 different protocols not in the same time necessarily but at least one of them in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a **testFunction** that try to get values for making an array of them. Since some types conform to **CustomStringConvertible** and some conform to **CustomDebugStringConvertible** I made 2 function with same name for each type. But I see Xcode complain about **ambiguous** issue, then I used deferent names which I would wish to keep the name like **testFunction** and not having **testFunction1** and **testFunction2**.

Here is my codes:

```
func testFunction1<T: CustomStringConvertible>(_ values: T...) {
    
    var array: [String] = [String]()

    values.forEach { value in

        array.append(value.description)
    }

    // other code to use array later ...

}

func testFunction2<T: CustomDebugStringConvertible>(_ values: T...) {
    
    var array: [String] = [String]()

    values.forEach { value in

        array.append(value.debugDescription)
    }

    // other code to use array later ...
 
}
```

**The issue is here:** It can be possible that I must receive mixed values with deferent types! Swift print function could handle it, but my 2 function cannot they can accept just type that conform to **CustomStringConvertible** or **CustomDebugStringConvertible**! I am trying to solve the mixed type issue, in this way that my testFunction could be able to **accept mixed value** like print does.

**Very important!** I am looking to solve the issue with the approach I am working. I am not looking for some kind of super protocol that covers **CustomStringConvertible** and **CustomDebugStringConvertible**.

use case:

```
print("Hello, world!", 1, CGFloat.pi, CGSize.zero)

testFunction1("Hello, world!", 1, CGFloat.pi, CGSize.zero)

testFunction2("Hello, world!", 1, CGFloat.pi, CGSize.zero)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Joakim Danielson is on the right path, but I would recommend this implementation to remove the duplication and the subtle filtering:

```
func testFunction(_ values: Any...) {
    let array: [String] = values.map {
        switch $0 {
        case let v as CustomStringConvertible: return v.description
        case let v as CustomDebugStringConvertible: return v.debugDescription
        default: return "\($0)"
        }
    }

    // other code to use array later ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that doesn't use generics

```
func testFunction1(_ values: Any...) {
    var array: [String] = [String]()

    values.forEach { value in
        switch value.self {
        case is CustomStringConvertible:
            array.append((value as! CustomStringConvertible).description)
        case is CustomDebugStringConvertible:
            array.append((value as! CustomDebugStringConvertible).debugDescription)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    // other code to use array later ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your array. Set your array to `var array: [T] = []`

Edit: try removing the generic constraints.

```
func testFunction1(_ values: CustomStringConvertible...) {
    
}

func testFunction2(_ values: CustomDebugStringConvertible...) {
    
}
```

Comment: @swiftPunk I've update my answer. I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible since CustomStringConvertible and CustomDebugStringConvertible don't inherit from a common protocol. The documentation also says NOT to use these protocols as generic constraints. Every value in swift is convertible to a string, regardless if it conforms to CustomStringConvertible.